# Trying to accessing Azure key vault for secrets in local and in Azure K8s

Tags: java, azure, docker, azure-aks, aws-secrets-manager

**I am trying get secrets from Key vault using DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder in my java application. Even after I got the below error, it works fine in local environement. I could get secrets value with key.**

*20-03-2023 05:59:58.225 [billingtrailers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] ERROR c.a.identity.EnvironmentCredential.506 - Azure Identity => ERROR in EnvironmentCredential: Missing required environment variable AZURE_CLIENT_ID
20-03-2023 05:59:58.324 [billingtrailers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] ERROR c.a.i.i.IntelliJCacheAccessor.506 - IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin in the IDE.
20-03-2023 06:00:00.983 [billingtrailers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] ERROR c.a.identity.EnvironmentCredential.506 - EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
20-03-2023 06:00:01.004 [billingtrailers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] ERROR c.a.i.implementation.IdentityClient.506 - ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established, Network is unreachable: connect.
20-03-2023 06:00:01.014 [billingtrailers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] ERROR c.a.i.ManagedIdentityCredential.506 - Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://vault.azure.net/.default]: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established, Network is unreachable: connect.*

**But the same application when deployed Azure K8s with docker image, I got different error and pod is not running due to that. Please see the error below.**

*19-03-2023 15:48:31.599 [billingtrailers-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators.315 - Operator called default onErrorDropped
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.microsoft.aad.msal4jextensions.persistence.linux.ISecurityLibrary (initialization failure)
at java.base/java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(Unknown Source)
at com.azure.identity.implementation.LinuxKeyRingAccessor.read(LinuxKeyRingAccessor.java:50)
at com.azure.identity.implementation.LinuxKeyRingAccessor.read(LinuxKeyRingAccessor.java:70)
at com.azure.identity.implementation.VisualStudioCacheAccessor.getCredentials(VisualStudioCacheAccessor.java:132)
at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.authenticateWithVsCodeCredential(IdentityClient.java:628)
at com.azure.identity.VisualStudioCodeCredential.lambda$getToken$2(VisualStudioCodeCredential.java:79)
at com.azure.identity.VisualStudioCodeCredential$$Lambda$995/0x00000000fc125a70.get(Unknown Source)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:790)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:894)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:997)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:903)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:259)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2063)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:142)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(MonoCompletionStage.java:83)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage$$Lambda$965/0x000000008512af90.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libsecret-1':
liblibsecret-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
liblibsecret-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.*

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The first log indicates that the client application is looking for the  [AZURE_CLIENT_ID environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet), which is typically the service principal application id.  The AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET and AZURE_TENANT_ID would also be needed.

The second log indicates a dependency is missing. It has been a long time since I used MSAL, but when I did I, in short found it difficult to know all dependencies that were required and solved it with brute force, the [Maven config did not seem to do it](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java).

Comment: Thanks @Hill5Air. I added the first set of logs for the reference. Even though there were errors, the application is running fine in local (windows) exeuting with jar. I got to know that AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET and AZURE_TENANT_ID not needed with DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder. I got issues with K8s pods (docker image) running in Azure linux env. see second set of logs